# lumen - LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage() is always 1

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination, lumen

With lumen, I have the problem that this is always `1`, also when I go to `/artikel?page=2`:

```
LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();
```

the complete code:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;


class ArtikelController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $dir = '../resources/views/artikel/';

        $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));

        $artikel = array();

        foreach($files as $k => $v)
        {
            $id = substr($v,0,1);
            $artikel[$id]['id'] = $id; 
            $artikel[$id]['name'] = substr($v,0,strpos($v,'.blade.php'));
        }

        //Get current page form url e.g. &page=6
        $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

#dd($currentPage);

        //Create a new Laravel collection from the array data
        $collection = new Collection($artikel);

        //Define how many items we want to be visible in each page
        $perPage = 2;

        //Slice the collection to get the items to display in current page
        $currentPageResults = $collection->slice($currentPage * $perPage, $perPage)->sortByDesc('id')->all();

        //Create our paginator and pass it to the view
        $paginatedResults = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageResults, count($collection), $perPage);

        $paginatedResults->setPath('artikel');

        return view('artikel', ['artikel' => $paginatedResults]);
    }
```

I can't find the mistake. What could be the reason? (I have also updated to `"laravel/lumen-framework": "5.1.*"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this simple way to get your current page:

```
$currentPage = (int) app('request')->get('page', $default = '0');
```